# Cloning Non enumerable properties in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have all non - enumerable properties in object, I want to clone that object.

My problem non-enumerable properties are not getting cloned.

Take below example

```
 Object.defineProperty(this, 'prop', {
        get: function () {
            return prop;
        },
        set: function (value) {
            prop= value;
        }
    });

   Object.defineProperty(this, 'newprop', {
        get: function () {
            return newprop;
        },
        set: function (value) {
            newprop= value;
        }
    });
```

For example I have above two properties in my object doing clone using following methods, my properties are not getting cloned I believe it is because they are non - enumerable.

```
   var newObject = $.extend({},oldObject);
   var newObject= Object.assign({},oldobject);
```

How do I copy non-enumerable properties in javascript.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If one or more properties aren't enumerable, how do you want to auto-magically enumerate them?

Since you know their names, you should do something like this:

```
var sourceObj = this;
var targetObj = {};

["prop", "otherProperty"].forEach(function(property) {
    targetObj[property] = sourceObj[property]; 
});
```

Or you can build the whole property name array whenever you define a non-enumerable property:

```
   var propertyNames = [];

   Object.defineProperty(this, 'newprop', {
        get: function () {
            return newprop;
        },
        set: function (value) {
            newprop= value;
        }
    });
    propertyNames.push("newprop"); // <---


   Object.defineProperty(this, 'newprop2', {
        get: function () {
            return newprop;
        },
        set: function (value) {
            newprop= value;
        }
    });
    propertyNames.push("newprop2"); // <---

propertyNames.forEach(function(property) {
    targetObj[property] = sourceObj[property]; 
});
```

### Alternate approach: `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`

> The `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` method returns an array of all
>   properties (enumerable or not) found directly upon a given object.

Maybe this is the best approach. [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) gets the name of own object's properties either if they're enumerable or not. That is, you can avoid building the whole `propertyNames` array, and **this approach should be fine with you because you said that all properties aren't enumerable**:

```
var sourceObj = this;
var targetObj = {};    

Object.getOwnPropertyNames(sourceObj).forEach(function(property) {
    targetObj[property] = sourceObj[property]; 
});
```

Comment: Sorry to confuse you, I have a object with all non - enumerable properties

Comment: @MaxMaddy This doesn't change the answer, does it?

Comment: @MaxMaddy See my update with an alternate approach ;P

Comment: Perfect :) Thank you

Comment: The "Alternate approach" need to be the only solution here. The first solution is bad bad practice!

Comment: Don't forget any [Symbol properties](https://www.keithcirkel.co.uk/metaprogramming-in-es6-symbols/):
`Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(sourceObj).forEach(function(property) {
    targetObj[property] = sourceObj[property]; 
});`

Be aware that this is just a level 1 deep cloning. That may be irrelevant if your objects are immutable though.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Object.defineProperties` and `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors()` function

> The `Object.defineProperties()` method defines new or modifies existing properties directly on an object, returning the object.

> The `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors()` method returns all own property descriptors of a given object.

So, you can add the properties of the original object into an empty object, as follow

```
var source_obj = this
var cloned_obj = Object.defineProperties({}, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(source_obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar question in [How to implement Ruby's extend module in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44186968/how-to-implement-rubys-extend-module-in-javascript/44187439?noredirect=1#comment75400157_44187439).

And because I don't wanna use iterate attach each method to new object, so the final best way I can do is like that, welcome give me any idea and suggestion, thanks.

```
class Test {

  constructor(name) {

    this.name = name;
  }

  test1(){
    return this.name + "test1"
  }
}

const Other = {
  test2: function(){
    return this.name + "test2"
  },

  test3: function(){
    return this.name + "test3"
  },

  test4: function(){
    return this.name + "test4"
  }

}

var person = new Test("HKE")
Object.assign(person,Other) //this like object.extend(Module) in ruby
console.log(person.test1()) // HKEtest1
console.log(person.test2()) // HKEtest2
console.log(person.test3()) // HKEtest3
console.log(person.test4()) // HKEtest4

var house = new Test("Tsao")
console.log(house.test1())
console.log(house.test2()) // TypeError: house.test2 is not a function
console.log(house.test3()) // TypeError: house.test3 is not a function
console.log(house.test4()) // TypeError: house.test4 is not a function
```