# How to implement Ruby's extend module in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js

In Ruby I can extend a module on a object at run time. I think JavaScript can get the function, but I can't get it to work.

Ruby runs OK, the object has `test1` and `test2` methods:

```
class Test

  def test1
    puts "test1"
  end

end

module Other
  def test2
    puts "test2"
  end
end

test = Test.new
test.extend(Other)
test.test1
test.test2
```

JavaScript returns a TypeError: test_new.test2 is not a function

```
class Test {
  test1(){
    console.log("test1")
  }
}

class Other {
  test2() {
    console.log("test2")
  }
}


console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames( Test.prototype ))
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames( Other.prototype ))

var test = new Test
var test_new = Object.assign(test, Other.prototype)
test_new.test1()
test_new.test2()
```

Does anyone know how I can get it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cloning Non enumerable properties in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38316864/218196).

Comment: @FelixKling, yes, I find it seems cause "Properties on the prototype chain and non-enumerable properties cannot be copied", thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cloning Non enumerable properties in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38316864/cloning-non-enumerable-properties-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

```
> class Test { test1(){ console.log("test1") }}    
> class Other { test2() { console.log("test2") }}
> test = new Test
Test {}
> other = new Other
Other {}
> test.test1()
test1
> test["test2"] = other.test2
> test.test2()
test2
```

An instance is really just an array of functions (in this case). So, when you call:

```
other.test2
```

It returns the `test2` element of `other` which is the function `test2`. And this:

```
> test["test2"] = other.test2
```

just add that function to the array of functions for `test`. Which you can then call with:

```
> test.test2()
```

Comment: Thanks, that's work, but if my Other class have many methods, and I don't wanna attach each method individually, how can I do?

Comment: Iterate the Other methods

Comment: I don't wanna Iterate, the code below I use seems the best way at least.

Comment: ````class Test {

  constructor(name) {
    //super(props);
  
    this.name = name;
  }

  test1(){
    return this.name
  }
}

const Other = {
  test2: function(){
    return this.name
  },

  test3: function(){
    return this.name
  }

}


console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames( Test.prototype ))
console.log(Test.prototype)

var test = new Test("HKE")
var test_new = Object.assign(test,Other)
console.log(test_new.test1())
console.log(test_new.test2())
console.log(test_new.test3())````

Comment: When did `wanna` become a word?

Comment: I replay my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38316864/cloning-non-enumerable-properties-in-javascript# , welcome to suggest.